# Show/Hide text field if statement doesn't execute properly

Tags: javascript, pdf, conditional-statements

I'm a complete novice when it comes to PDF editing/Java. I was assigned a task at work to revise our payment request PDF form. I pieced together code found online for my purposes and it worked so far. But now I'm coming across what I believe needs to be an "if statement" and it doesn't work.

I have a dropdown list (`Vendor_name`) which depending on selection auto populates other fields on the form. I have it working so far that if a user selects "Other" as the vendor being payed, additional 8 text fields show up. 4 of those fields are just text such as "bank name", "bank account number", etc, and the other 4 are for the user to enter the information.

My problem now is that I'm trying to modify the 4 additional informational fields to display a different kind of text when vendor "FICA" is selected. Example: when "FICA" is selected I want the text box to read "TAX ID NO" instead of "Bank Name". 
But now I have TAX ID NO displayed no matter if the selection is "Other" or "FICA".

I have all 9 fields hidden until "Other" or "Fica" is selected. My code for that is in Calculate--> Custom calculation script, which works fine:

```
if (this.getField("Vendor_name").value == "Other" || this.getField("Vendor_name").value == "FICA"){      //replace "dropdown" with the name of the dropfield
event.target.display = display.visible;
}
else{
event.target.display = display.hidden;
}
```

the code below is my attempt at having it display the different values based on selection from dropdown:

Format-->Custom Format Script:

```
if (this.getField("Vendor_name").value == "Other"){
event.value = "Vendor/Payee Name";
}
else{
event.value = "TAX ID No.";
}
```

I have 2 snippets below.

[image: Format-->custom script snippet]
[image: Calculate-->custom script snippet]

Comment: First thing to know is that Java and JavaScript are completely different programming languages.

Comment: I've got to ask; what is that editor you are using? JavaScript can be used in many different contexts and knowing what context you're using it in will affect answers a great degree.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm working within the PDF form itself. I right click on the button itself, open properties, and from there format--> edit.

Comment: Ah! PDF! There was nothing in the question or title mentioning PDF; Maybe there was a tag on [su] that didn't get migrated or something. I've added the `pdf` tag so the right experts get eyes on the question.